# Java: Possible Lossy Conversion from long to int

Tags: java

Every time I try to execute this code it tells me that there is a lossy conversion from long to int. To my knowledge, there is not a single int in this code. The only thing I suspect is that one of the functions only returns an int. If so, how do I convert that into a long?

Also, does anyone see any errors in the last tow lines? I'm trying to convert an array into a list and I'm not sure that will work

And yes, I am aware that there are many other issues here, I'm just focused on this one specifically

```
import java.util.List;
class SumDigPower {
public static List<Long> sumDigPow(long a, long b) {
  long solution = 0;
  long solutionCounter = 0;
  long[] solutionArray;
  long[] digitArray;
  for (long i = a; i < b; i++) { 
    String strLong = Long.toString(i);
    String[] strArray = strLong.split("");
    for (long j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++) {
      digitArray[j] = Long.parseLong(strArray[j]);
    } for (long k = 0; k < digitArray.length; k++) {
      solution += Math.pow((k+1), digitArray[k]);
    } if (solution == i) {
      solutionArray[solutionCounter] = solution;
      solution = 0;
      solutionCounter += 1;
    }
  } List<Long> solutionList = Arrays.asList(solutionArray);
  return solutionList;
}
}
```

Comment: This code should not compile. The array index should be an int value and you use a long. For example :  `digitArray[j] =` where `j` is declared as a `long`.

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues, the one you're asking about is easy enough - valid array indices are `int` (not `long`).

Comment: Even when I change those indices to ints the problem still remains with solutionArray[solutionCounter] = solution;

Answer (score 1):

Valid array indices are `int` (not `long`). You can't use an array without initializing it (and you need to know the length, because that's fixed with Java arrays). Next, you are wanting a `List<Long>` and trying to build an array (again, you can't do that - just use a `List<Long>` to begin with - and you can eliminate `solutionCounter`). Like,

```
public static List<Long> sumDigPow(long a, long b) {
    long solution = 0;
    List<Long> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for (long i = a; i < b; i++) {
        String strLong = Long.toString(i);
        String[] strArray = strLong.split("");
        long[] digitArray = new long[strArray.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++) {
            digitArray[j] = Long.parseLong(strArray[j]);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < digitArray.length; k++) {
            solution += Math.pow((k + 1), digitArray[k]);
        }
        if (solution == i) {
            al.add(solution);
            solution = 0;
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pick a value from from an array with a long. Try casting to int instead:

```
long myLong = 0;
int myInt = (int) i;
```

and then putting it as your index in an array:

```
myStringArray[myInt]
```